# Add dynamic html to fancy box

Tags: fancybox

Been using FancyBox to display a swf player.  What I would like to do is have an if statement that, when false adds the flash vars to 'swf': {...}, which I have working.  And when true displays some inline markup.

```
if (true) {
    $.fancybox({
        'type': inline
        //can I ref markup here???
    });
} else {
    $.fancybox({
        'href' : somepath,
        'type': 'swf',
        'swf': {..}
    });
}
```

Would someone be able to advise on how I can either reference the markup using the approach above.  Or if I can even add dynamic html here, which would be a nicer approach.

Thanks in advance

Eddie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this.

I needed to use the key content, which forces `FancyBox` to load the html content:

```
if(true){
  var content = $('#someHtml').html();
  $.fancybox({
      'content': content,
      'padding' : 20
  });
}else{...}
```