# Fancybox can't generate slides when content is html

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-2

I don't know if it's a bug, or if it's just something fancybox doesn't permit.
Is it posible to have a gallery with HTML elements ?
I'm trying to do it since hours but can't find the good way to it.

The HTML :

```
<a href="#" class="fancy" data-fancybox-type="html" rel="fancy">See more</a>
<div class="content">my content 1</div>
<a href="#" class="fancy" data-fancybox-type="html" rel="fancy">See more</a>
<div class="content">my content 2</div>
<a href="#" class="fancy" data-fancybox-type="html" rel="fancy">See more</a>
<div class="content">my content 3</div>
```

The javascript :

```
jQuery(".fancy").on('click', function(){
    jQuery.fancybox({
        content: jQuery(this).next().html(),
        scrolling: 'no',
        autoSize: false ,
        height:250,
        width:630,
        padding:0
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877282/add-dynamic-html-to-fancy-box there are small differences. 1. asign jQuery(this).next().html(); outside the .fancybox() 2. add '' like in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to have a gallery of `html` elements, however you need to understand first what exactly you mean with that.

If what you want is to have "*my content 1*", "*my content 2*" and "*my content 3*" (as in your code above) within a fancybox gallery, then you have to structure your html properly.

First, every link should point to a specific content by targeting its ID like :

```
<a href="#content1" class="fancy" rel="fancy">See more (content 1)</a>
```

... the line above implies that you have the `content 1` html like :

```
<div id="content1" class="content">my content 1</div>
```

... so the text `my content 1` will be the actual `content` of the first item of the gallery (links that share the same `rel` attribute will be part of the fancybox gallery)

You can group all your targeted content inside a hidden `div` like :

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="content1" class="content">my content 1</div>
    <div id="content2" class="content">my content 2</div>
    <div id="content3" class="content">my content 3</div>
</div>
```

and leave your links visible only

```
<a href="#content1" class="fancy" rel="fancy">See more (content 1)</a>
<a href="#content2" class="fancy" rel="fancy">See more (content 2)</a>
<a href="#content3" class="fancy" rel="fancy">See more (content 3)</a>
```

See the gallery working in this <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qB287/)</kbd>

On the other hand, if you use the `data-fancybox-type="html"` attribute, fancybox will actually parse **html code**, so if you have a link as in the example above for instance

```
<a href="#content1" class="fancy" data-fancybox-type="html" rel="fancy">See more (content 1)</a>
```

... the content of fancybox won't be `my content 1` as in the jsfiddle referred above but `#content1` because fancybox will parse the html of the link instead

See new <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N6BLp/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".fancy").on('click', function(){
        var content = $(this).next().html();
        $.fancybox({
            'content': content
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLUfj/)  (didn't add all options)

make sure to include the right jQuery and Fancybox scripts see [here](http://fancybox.net/howto)

Comment: I think my question wasn't enough clear.
I want to use it as a slideshow, pass to the next item by a next button and to the item before with a back button.